# How to reload page the page with pagination in Angular 2?

Tags: angular, refresh, angular2-routing, reload, page-refresh

How can I reload the current page on Angular 2?

if iam in page 2 (pagination) and refresh the page it will show page 1(URL pageload)
but i want i refresh the page 2 and it will appear in page 2

Comment: What do you want to achieve by reloading? May be there are alternate ways to achieve the same?

Comment: @MadhuRanjan
 i want to reset all the model
but not value after value,

Comment: you may have all model fetch functions in a common method and call it when ever needed.

Comment: @MadhuRanjan
is it impassable to repload page simlpy?

Comment: sure can, you can use `window.location.reload()` like in below answer, But it defies the purpose of SPA, Cheers!!

Comment: @MadhuRanjan
but it not cross platform way

Comment: what platform you are targeting? It is supported in all major Browsers, IE\Edge\Chrome\Firefox\Safari.

Comment: @MadhuRanjan
if i run with chrome on linux windows.location will not work

Comment: usually Browser features work irrespective of platform, if it is available officially for the respective OS. Having said that I would suggest you to  create a new SO question regarding how to get around `window.location.reload()` for chrome on Linux, that would be ideal place for getting your answer, and then you may have a check in your code to get the browser version and have a logic around,  Cheers!!

Comment: FWIW, my own use case for this is multi-language support, since as of v5.1, Angular still doesn't support it without doing a separate deployment per language. I have a Razor page that decides which Angular script bundle to load, depending on the language preference it gets from the user database of the ASP.NET Core backend. In order to change the language after the user has changed their preferences, reloading just the Angular SPA won't do, I need to reload the entire Razor page to basically have it load a different Angular SPA.

Comment: You can call the ngOnInit() method

Answer (score 263):

This should technically be achievable using `window.location.reload()`:

**HTML:**

```
<button (click)="refresh()">Refresh</button>
```

**TS:**

```
refresh(): void {
    window.location.reload();
}
```

**Update:**

Here is a basic [StackBlitz](https://angular-zhdfqe.stackblitz.io/hello) example showing the refresh in action. Notice the URL on "/hello" path is retained when `window.location.reload()` is executed.

Comment: i want better way windows.location
that not cross platform...

Comment: There is no simple cross platform way.  You would have to check what platform it is and then do the appropriate reload for that platform.

Comment: The refresh doesn't work and only brings the user back to the first page.

Comment: It can depend on how your routing is set up as well as how SPA routes are loaded by the server. `reload()` is a standard browser approach to reloading resources from the current URL.