# How to refresh angular 7 page on rights way?

Tags: angular

what is the right way to reload page not router?

I saw E.g window.location.reload() but its not a good practice in SSR right?

Comment: You're going to have to be more explicit on your needs : `Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the How To Ask page for help clarifying this question.`

Comment: ([ask] & [mcve])

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to reload page the whole page in Angular 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43985752/how-to-reload-page-the-whole-page-in-angular-2)

Answer (score 0):

There is no `this is the way`. I've running a big application and we setup a websocket reload event to force every client to reload the application with `window.location.reload(true)`, so that we can build and publish a new version of the application and forces everyone to use the new one so that nothing breaks.

For angular itself there is only the router option:

```
@ngModule({
 imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {onSameUrlNavigation: ‘reload’})],
 exports: [RouterModule],
 })
```