Angular 18 standalone - paramMap changed in router but app won't reload
Here is my code:
 <li class="nav-item dropdown">
   <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
     Photos
   </a>
   <ul class="dropdown-menu">
     <li *ngFor="let p of photoMenu">
       <a class="dropdown-item" [routerLink]="['/photos', p.param]">{{ p.title }}</a>
     </li>
   </ul>
 </li>

  public ngOnInit(): void {
    this.paramsSub = this.activedRoute.paramMap
      .subscribe(
        (params: any | ParamMap) => {
          this.val.photoFolder = params.get('folder'),
            this.val.fileFolder = this.mediaConfig.AssetPhotoFolder + "/" + params.get('folder') + "/";
          this.photoParam = this.val;
         /* this.route.navigateByUrl(this.route.url);*/
        }
      )
  }

My app loads once. What ever in p.param changed, my app did not reload. I tried to put onload function in ngOninit() and constructor() and they stay still not working.
Any suggestion?

If you want to reload page when you are on same route with different parameters you can enable onSameUrlNavigation:'reload' in the route config
export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
  providers: [
    provideRouter(
      appRoutes,
      withRouterConfig({ onSameUrlNavigation: 'reload' })
    ),
  ],
};


Thanks. However, it still not run the ngOnInit().  I put it in the construction() and it is not working either.  I wonder it is a bug because it is a STANDALONE app.

You can try this:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43985752/how-to-reload-page-the-page-with-pagination-in-angular-2 if you want to reload the entire page.

I don't think the window.location.reload will apply to this situation. Thanks.  The issue occurred prior Angular 18.  It has been fixed.  Now it happens again...It should be a solution or (how to get around etc...).
